# error while install app from terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, wine

many masters in here. I just have some problem while installing software via terminal. for example, I want to install wine with the code `sudo apt-get install wine`. But terminal said this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shotwell : Depends: shotwell-common (= 0.18.0-0ubuntu4) but 0.18.0-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

anyone wants to help me ? great thanks for all of you masters.

Comment: Do you have any third-party repositories enabled?

Comment: how can i know if i have enabled third-party repositories?? I'm sorry, I'm a new user. great thanks for you

Comment: You can edit your question with the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and also of any file in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. (To view a file you can run the command `gedit /path/to/file`.)

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get -f install` as suggested by @Zeus77 would also be a good idea in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a broken package.

Run `$ sudo aptitude -f install` to fix that first, and then go on to install *wine*.

Though, personally I prefer using **playonlinux**, in automatically handles the wine version etc. for you and keeps apps in different wineprefixes, gets less messy that way.